# If $\int_2^{x^2}x\cdot f(s) ds=2x^5-x^4+2$, then find $f(9)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{2}^{x^2}x\cdot f(s)ds=2x^5-x^4+2\quad(x>0)\Rightarrow f(9)=?$$

I would have taken the derivative of both sides of the equation if the integral was not definite. In this case, I don't have a valid solution.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? That integral notation is... not good.

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x) \int_2^{x^2} x \mathrm dx$$ on the LHS?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at MathJax. I edited my question

Comment: @EldarRahimli that helped a little, but it's still strange. What does it mean to integrate $xf(x)$ with respect to $x$ from $2$ to $x^2$? There are at least one too many $x$'s there.

Comment: I checked again, this is exactly what I've been given

Comment: @Arthur I don't think that notation is unusual (to reuse the variable on integration in the bound, being "different" $x$s), though strictly they should be using a different variable.

Comment: The integration part should have 2 variables

Comment: 'strictly they should be using a different variable' Exactly. So I would say $\int_2^{x^2}tf(t)dt = 2x^5-x^4+2$. The phrase 'being "different" $x$s' should never be a thing one has to specify.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote, Yes, that part looked strange to me as well. In most of the problems I have solved, integration was using a different variable. Does this make the problem erroneous?

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I think that is highly unusual and, most probably, a mistake. The integration variable *must* be different from the one(s) on the integral's limits, otherwise the problem could be considered ill posed, imo.

Comment: I would say 13 is the answer, but I'm getting contradictions. Are you sure the last constant is $+2$?

Comment: You are correct, the answer is given as $13$. Yes, the last constant is $+2$

Comment: Instead of  $\;2\;$ it can be some constant...and perhaps it **must** be so, as Saad answer shows...It is a problem of writing correctly the question. Maybe it should be "for some $\;x\;$ it happens that...", or with a constant in the RHS, stating "there exists a constant such that..." .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution was posted before the question was edited.

Use Chain Rule. The derivative of LHS is $x^{2}f(x^{2}) (2x)$. Put $x=3$ after differentiating.

For the revised version first divide by $x$, then apply Chain Rule and put $x=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Realize that the $x$ in $dx$ (and in $xf(x)$) is a dummy variable. It means that we can replace it with anything without anything changing - so LHS reads:

$$\text{LHS}(x) = \int\limits_2^{x^2} t f(t) dt$$

It should be now clear - if you take the derivative with respect to $x$ you need only to take care in the $x$ dependence in the upper limit. If you don't know how to deal with this kind of derivatives then first set $x^2 = y$, take derivative with respect to $y$ and figure out how derivative w.r.t. $y$ relates to one w.r.t. $x$.

Answer (score 2):

There does not exist such $f$ since otherwise$$
0 = \int_2^{(\sqrt{2})^2} y f(y) \,\mathrm{d}y = 2(\sqrt{2})^5 - (\sqrt{2})^4 + 2 = 8\sqrt{2} - 2 ≠ 0,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: @MariaMazur What? As given, the question implies that the equality is true for *any* $\;x\;$ ...so this answer is correct. Now, if there are some constraints then they must be explicitly stated.

Comment: @MariaMazur As clarified in the comments below the question, the unambiguous notation is $\displaystyle\int_2^{x^2}t·f(t)\,\mathrm dt=2x^5-x^4+2$. And even if it were to mean $\displaystyle\int_2^{x^2}x·f(t)\,\mathrm dt=2x^5-x^4+2$, the deduction above still leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I can agree with those interpretations but not as it is stated.